# Side swipe gesture not working properly

Tags: swift

I have a variable of type integer, when I want to swipe left I want to increment the variable by one. And conversely, deincrement the varaible by one with a swipe right gesture.

the problem is when I swipe left, the switch statement doesn't recognise and execute the code e.g when the variable is one. It only executes it if I go back OVER one. Why doesn't the switch statement recognise the swipe left statements too. I am currently just outputting to the console.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

//counter varaible
var counter:Int = 0


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    println(counter)

    //swipe left
    let swipeLeft:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swipedLeft:")
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

    //swipe right

    let swipeRight:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swipedRight:")
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
}

//swiped Left
func swipedLeft(didLeft:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

    counter += 1
    println(counter)
}


//swiped right
func swipedRight(didRight:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

    counter -= 1
    println(counter)

    switch counter {
    case 1:
        println("one")
    case 2:
        println("two")
    default:
        println("bye")
    }


}
```

Comment: "when I swipe left, the switch statement doesn't recognise and execute the code" "Why doesn't the switch statement recognise the swipe left statements too"



Because your swiped left function doesn't have a switch statement in it?